# How to upgrade numpy version on Ubuntu 14.04 (Mint 17)

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv, apt-get

I want to install tenosrflow python's package on my Linux Mint 17 (which mimics Ubuntu 14.04), but it requires numpy to be newer than 1.8.2.

When I'm trying to update by pip it says the following thing:

```
Cannot uninstall 'numpy'. It is a distutils installed project and thus we cannot accurately determine which files belong to it which would lead to only a partial uninstall.
```

If I try to purge numpy with apt-get purge, it replies that it has to uninstall some important packages also, and that scares me.

virtualenv doesn't help either.

Can someone recommend what to do?

Comment: You have tried using sudo apt-get, right?

Comment: try `easy_install numpy`, that should upgrade numpy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this ...

```
pip install --ignore-installed numpy
```

For more details on this topic refer to this [Link](https://github.com/blockstack/blockstack-core/issues/504)

Comment: well, I don't think it would work until numpy was upgraded.

Comment: Thought it works for the guy who shared this code on github, please check the [Link](https://github.com/blockstack/blockstack-core/issues/504)

Comment: Thank you, in combination with virtualenv it helped!